# MySQL Query Retrieving name of straight-A students

Tags: mysql, sql

I will start by saying this is for Homework and I am not looking for a solution. I am only looking for confirmation/tips about what I have already tried. Basically, there are Tables:

STUDENT(Name, Student_number, Class, Major)

GRADE_REPORT(Student_number, Section_identifier, Grade)

I need to retrieve the names and major departments of all straight-A student (Students who have a grade of A in all their courses).

This is what I have come up with:

```
SELECT Name, Major
FROM STUDENT s JOIN GRADE_REPORT g
        ON s.Student_number = g.Student_number
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT Grade
    FROM GRADE_REPORT
    WHERE Grade <> ‘A’ 
          AND Student_number = s.Student_number)
```

Again, only looking for confirmation and tips about writing the query. I am pretty new to writing queries and am still a little confused as to the logic behind it.

Comment: I think the `JOIN` operation is  redundant, the rest of the query is OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are differents way to this.

In your try. Your first part doesnt need the `JOIN`. You are bringing student and the where filter the student you dont want. If you look carefull you realize dont use anything from the `GRADE_REPORT` table.

```
SELECT Name, Major
FROM STUDENT s JOIN GRADE_REPORT g
        ON s.Student_number = g.Student_number
```

But even with that addtional `JOIN` should bring you the result you want.

Now a better solution is use the `JOIN` and use `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` to filter the students

```
SELECT Name, Major
FROM STUDENT s 
JOIN GRADE_REPORT g
  ON s.Student_number = g.Student_number
GROUP BY Name, Major
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN g.Grade <> 'A' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Now here you join both table and use a `CONDITIONAL COUNT` to see how many of the student grades arent `'A'`, and only will return those with 0

The advantage is removing the subquery improve the general performance

Comment: Also instead of using having, he can use
WHERE s.Student_number NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Student_number FROM GRADE_REPORT WHERE Grade <> 'A')

Comment: @HerpaMoTeH `NOT IN` and `NOT EXIST` are very similar and the use depend on what are you doing or what index you have. But in this case using the `HAVING` you save to perform a sub query for each row.

Comment: I'm not completely sure that you are performing the subquery for each and every row. Instead the query is done once and the end result is used to create an array for the IN clause.

Comment: @HerpaMoTeH Every row has a different subquery, because on the subquery you need the `s.Student_number` from the row.

Comment: And can you tell me where in my subquery I've used a table from the main query ?

Comment: @HerpaMoTeH Ok my mistake, I tought your was similar to OP query. Still   dont like the idea of using the `not in` because wont use any index, but the best would be try both and check the explain plan.

Comment: Let's suppose that the OP has indexed his ID,  that STUDENT.Student_number is a PK and GRADE_REPORT.Student_number is a foreign key.

Comment: But the moment you create a sub query wont have index anymore, if data is small wont matter, but if data is big the performance will drop. Again the best way is test it, not all cases are equal.

Comment: The explanations to go along with the logic really helped me understand what was actually going on. The [CASE WHEN _condition_ THEN __ END] syntax is new to me and could be very helpful with some of these queries. Thank you very much because I am always concerned with performance on these.